# How to search UPC barcode from excel cell in vba form?

Tags: json, excel, vba, barcode

I have an inventory database in excel with user input form with next and previous buttons that show earlier entered data. How can I add an option to, let say "look up barcode" button it would automatically search it in the www.upcitemdb.com website. It has API with JSON, but Im not sure if I even need that, and I wouldn't know how anyways. All I need is once the lookup button is entered it would open browser and automatically search the barcode that was in the barcode cell in the sheet.
Thanks for your help.

Had a look at the API, but I don't know Java script.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    MultiPage1.Value = 0
    Call resetForm

         With Worksheets("Data")
    ComboBox1.List = .Range(.Range("A1"), .Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Value
    End With

    With Worksheets("Data")
    ComboBox2.List = .Range(.Range("B1"), .Range("B1").End(xlDown)).Value
    End With

    'ComboBox1.ListRows = 8


    ' Set the first item in combobox
    ComboBox1.ListIndex = 0
    ComboBox2.ListIndex = 0


'worksheet with your data
    Set wsDatabase = Sheets("Inventory")
        'find last row in data range
        LastRow = wsDatabase.Cells(wsDatabase.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        'Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    'start at first record
    r = LastRow

    'or from activecell
    'r = ActiveCell.Row - 1


    Navigate Direction:=r


End Sub
```

Comment: I would break this into smaller problems and ask separate questions. Is the first problem how to add an option to a userform?

Answer (score 0):

> once the lookup button is entered it would open browser and
>   automatically search the barcode that was in the barcode cell in the
>   sheet

this has an easy fix:

copy the function below, put the complete url with / at the end, add the barcode, voilà. good old friend IE shows up right away.

```
Sub gotopage(url As String, barcode As String)
    Shell ("C:\Program Files\internet explorer\iexplore.exe " & url & barcode)
End Sub
```